# find the next specific element using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a problem on this, i want to enabled the select element by checking the check box that correspond the select element in a row. how can i do that?

```
<table>
<?php do { ?>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
 <td>
    <select disabled="disabled">
     <option value="1">Dog</option>
     <option value="2">Cat</option>
    </select>
 </td>
</tr>
<?php } while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this is Javascript like create a function like

```
function CheckMe(field)
{
    var tr = field.parentNode.parentNode;
    var select = tr.getElementsByTagName("select");

    if(select.length>0)
    {
        if(field.checked)
        {
            select[0].removeAttribute("disable");
        }
        else
        {
            select[0].setAttribute("disable", "disable")  
        }
    }
}
```

and change in you php do loop

```
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
```

to

```
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="CheckMe(this)" /></td>
```

Comment: Good, clean answer though I prefer not to use event attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In plain javascript, this code will enable the select list in the same row when the checkbox is checked and disable it when it is unchecked:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var checkboxes = table.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        var select = row.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        if (this.checked) {
           select.removeAttribute("disabled");
        } else {
           select.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }, false);
}​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/w8ZUj/

FYI - this uses `addEventListener` which is not supported in older versions of IE.  A suitable cross browser replacement that substitutes `addEvent` in IE can be used if older versions of IE must be supported.

Comment: The way to go imo, though `row.getElementsByTagName("select")[0]` could be potentially undefined.

Comment: @Christoph - that depends upon the OP's HTML.  It would only be undefined if there's no matching `select` element for a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given you answers based on parentNode, however a more general solution can be used with a simlpe *upTo* function, e.g.

```
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  var el;
  do {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  } while (el.parentNode)
}
```

So to get the select element, the listener would be something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="doSelect(this);">
```

where *doSelect* is:

```
function doSelect(el) {
  var sel;
  var row = upTo(el, 'tr');

  if (row) {
    sel = row.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
  }

  if (sel) {
    sel.disabled = !el.checked;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add onchange event to the checkbox as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="enableSelect(this)" />
```

and then use this javascript code to enable the selectbox in the same row as the checkbox

```
function enableSelect(checkbox) {
    var selectElements = checkbox.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select");
    selectElements[0].disabled = !checkbox.checked;
}
```

Comment: No, but it would have been easier if @avien used jQuery to accomplish this. Can't you read the first line? It is just a suggestion.

Comment: @Christoph - there is a javascript tag, so I don't see why a Javascript solution wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the response guys.. anyway i forgot to ask, is there anyway to solve this problem without using jquery? just pure javascript will do.

Comment: @Spudley javascript != jQuery

Comment: i mean just the pure and traditional approach of using javascript ;)

Comment: @Christoph - jQuery is a javascript library. If the OP was okay with a JS answer, and didn't specify jQuery or not, it's reasonable to offer a jQuery solution. Fair enough; OP has *now* clarified he doesn't wan JQ, but this was a reasonable attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Spudley - the convention I've seen here on SO is that you ONLY offer a jQuery answer if the question is tagged with jQuery.  If not, then assume plain javascript.

Comment: Updated the answer to use javascript instead of jQuery. I hope everyone is happy now :)

Comment: +1 for using javascript instead of jquery -1 for using event attributes , +0.5 for at least putting it in a separate function. Too bad there are no half points on SO;)